# Enable .htaccess file in OS-X Mavericks

Tags: apache, .htaccess, osx-mavericks

I have my website code at `/Library/WebServer/Documents/edu` and I'm using the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

which I've put under `/Library/WebServer/Documents/edu`, but apache server seems to be  ignoring this file and whatever changes I'm doing here are not taking effect.
Do I need to do some additional changes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Apache has .htaccess disabled, so you would have to enable it.

Go to and edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

You will find a section that looks like this:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

You have to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` and then find the section right after which should start with: `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">` and you'll have to change the same thing there to `AllowOverride All`

Comment: If I understand Apache configuration correctly, you actually wouldn't need to edit the default unless you wanted to globally enable it *without* the need to edit the secondary configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obsolete post Apache 2.4

The right way is:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents" 

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents"> 

    AllowOverride all

    Allow from all

</Directory>
```